# With Rails, How can I expire the Browser's cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, browser, caching

I have an issue with my Rails application and the browser's cache: When a user logs out of the authenticated section of the site, they are still able to use the back button on the browser to see the authenticated page. I do not want to allow this.

How can I expire the cache and force it to reload.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following headers should do that. Whatever page you're trying protect, add them there.

```
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: "now"
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

Obviously, the **now** needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe, you might also want to specify

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

in your pages.